# Stack Overflow real time world map

Tags: support

I remember seeing something like a Stack Overflow real time questions map one or two years ago (showing where in the world questions were coming from). However, I already searched, and I cannot find anything related to this.

Is that still available ?

Comment: What was it a map of?  Countries where questions were coming from?

Comment: Exactly ! That is what I am looking for.

Comment: I think this was an entry to a Stack Apps competition a while ago

Comment: Wasn't there a live screen in the SE offices at some point?

Comment: Yes I also saw it on the SE offices. But I am pretty sure that I accessed that map. It was very cool.

Comment: You probably meant [The Stack Big Board (with Video!)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/the-stack-big-board/)

Comment: https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc#!countries

Comment: Yes I also saw that video on that occasion, but the website that I am refering to was accessible to everybody popping those new questions every 20 seconds and then fading away.