# Real time SE specific traffic page?

Tags: feature-request, traffic

This is really random and probably will get closed fast, but how about making an SE page where we could see real time traffic on the site, animated questions/answers/comments/votes continually poping out. It would probably end up with us staring at it all the time, so maybe not the best thing...

I am aware that SE is actually tracked by Quantcast ([Stack Overflow real time world map](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195949/stack-overflow-real-time-world-map)), but that is "just" traffic tracking (although very good one), this is more about something supported from the site itself (having the key events mentioned above accessible from single place). Maybe this is possible without site support through some developers API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can watch a real-time list of post activity (questions asked, answers posted and posts edited, as a live auto-updating list) at

- https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime