# Real-time, site-specific traffic indicators?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Are there any real-time indicators of site traffic available?  I'm aware of [Real time SE specific traffic page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314075/real-time-se-specific-traffic-page), and my question is different.

I'm thinking more along the lines of access to real-time data such as number of people currently viewing something/anything on the site, number of users currently logged into the site, or number of site pages currently being viewed; basically raw data that is likely collected automatically and doesn't require much processing resources for summarizing, aggregating, or filtering.  This could be one or more such indicators that could either be displayed routinely as a count and identifying label, or some form of query that could be run.  Or might there be a user script that does this?

Comment: You can see visits per day on the [sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) though I'm not sure how often this is recalculated. I doubt you'll get something more than this since calculating something like this is computationally expensive and heavily cached (note for example the discrepancies when searching for `views:####`).

Comment: @Laurel, thanks.  Yeah, there are some sources of stats, like in the analytics, that give averages and "historical" numbers.  I was looking for a way to get some indication of how many people are on the site "right now".   I assume people running the web site see numbers like that, but maybe it's at a broader scale.

Comment: What would be the advantage in being able to see this?

Comment: Personally I'd find this interesting particularly if broken down by IP address (or rough range for anonymity preservation). Just from the point of view of peoplewatching - how the numbers dip during important news events, if they're affected by the World-Cup final much, the weather etc..

Comment: @Luuklag, my own interest is mainly about activity timing.  Some actions benefit from a lot of people seeing it quickly, and some actions might be disruptive, so the fewer people using the site the better; knowing roughly how many people are currently using the site would help.  This would probably be less useful on the big sites; on tiny sites, there's a much bigger relative range of traffic extremes.

Comment: The closest I can think of is the [/events](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events) endpoint of the API.